# Get the userid in telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using `@username_to_id_bot` to retrieve the `user_id`.
Sometimes the user doesn't have a username.
How can I retrive in this case?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the user id while already chatting with the user? or before starting a conversation?

Comment: During chat for example

Comment: See answer, hope it helps (I do this with the Python library but I think it is the same with other languages)

Comment: which library are you using or how do you get a @username?

Comment: you can also forward message from the user to the same @username_to_id_bot and get id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each user response the Telegram payload includes information like user_id and chat_id.
You can always access these navigating the JSON.

When processing a simple text response

```
update.message.from_user.id
```

When processing a Callback Query

```
update.callback_query.from_user.id
```

Comment: I need to create a bot ? I can't get it from a normal account?

Comment: Uhm, I dont think so as you need to use the payload which is not visible in the Telegram app.

Comment: Can I add bot functions to a normal account? I mean, a normal user could be BOT (with keyboard inline etc) and normal user where I can chat with the user?

Comment: Thats possible: every account has its own tokens (which you get from the Bot Father) so you can connect a bot or just reply from within the action. You will need to decide when the bot responds (only for Callabacks for example) and when to ignore the message

Answer (score -1):

If you are using web application, in address bar you can see URL like following:
`https://web.telegram.org/#/im?p=u1111111111_2222222222222222222`

In this case `1111111111` is the `user_id` which you are looking for.